# What printer can I use for On-Demand industrial Printing with a .Net application?

Tags: c#, .net, barcode-printing

I am developing a software system for a plastics factory. My aim is to have 10 barcode labelling printers, one printer for each plastics extruding machine. I do not want these printers to be very intelligent. Each printer will have an ID (1-10) and when a print button is pressed on the printer, a signal is sent via the network to a .Net application which will be listening and therefore send back a label to print depending on the ID of the printer.

This is not the sort of question I would normally ask on here, but I cannot find a printer that will suit my needs... or more accurately do not know what sort of terminology to use when searching.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I used to work in a facility that had lots of Zebra printers. I am not sure you will find a 'printer' that can do what you want, but this could be accomplish with a PLC fairly easily.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unaware of any barcode printers that have buttons that fire an event like this.

I would suggest using a series of USB buttons and programatically mapping them to specific printers.

http://www.thegoodlifeoncampus.com/Dream-Cheeky-Big-Red-Button-USB-gadget-p/dc1014.htm

Comment: Haha! I love that little gadget! I maybe didnt explain properly. The printer is just a regular label printer, all labels are designed server side with the barcode on them. The print signal just needs to be sent to the printer. But the print initiated on the print side. It is for a factory worker to simply press a button and a label comes out

Comment: Yeah, that's what I understood by "when a print button is pressed on the printer". I've been dealing with barcode printers for a long time and I'm unaware of any way to do this. I *believe* that the print button is typically handled by the printer and doesn't send signals back to the computer. I'd suggest a different solution: the buttons are bolted somewhere near the printer but are connected to a computer with some software that just handles these buttons and printers.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have make a button and glue it on to the printer as far I'm aware and then wire it up to something.

Last time I worked in this area we just used product tracking and when it detected the product approaching the labelling station, it printed the label so it was ready. Lot of stuff already in place to do that though. Then some poor git could stand there for hours just hanging them on it as it went past.